# PHP populated button onclick issue

Tags: php, javascript, dom

I'm having an issue where i populate a button with an onclick, i see that in the HTML once its populated (after the document is first loaded) the onclick is there, but it wont trigger the function, heres the PHP code:

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo('<div class="row">
    <div class="col"><span>Company Name: ' . $row['CompanyName'] . '</span></div>
    <div class="col"><span>Telephone: ' . $row['CustomerNumber'] . '</span></div>
    <div class="col"><span>Access Code: ' . $row['AccessCode'] . '</span></div>
    <div class="col"><span>Active: ' . $row['Active'] . '</span></div>
    <input type="button" value="Delete" onClick="javascript:delete(this);"></input></div><br />');
```

The delete function is on the same page as the populated button (function delete(e){}), any ideas why it wouldn't trigger?

Note there are no JS errors and javascript is enabled (can call a function directly from the browser)

EDIT:

Heres 1 line from the HTML output:

```
    <br>
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
<span>Company Name: TBC</span>
</div>
<div class="col">
<span>Telephone: 354</span>
</div>
<div class="col">
<span>Access Code: </span>
</div>
<div class="col">
<span>Active: </span>
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="delete(this);" value="Delete">
</div>
```

Comment: you don't need the `javascript:` part there ;)

Comment: what's in your `delete` javascript function?

Comment: p.s. you should be using ',' (echo can take multiple arguments) instead of '.' (string concatenation)

Comment: Can you post the generated HTML?

Comment: Topener thanks, removed, no effect though.
powtac sorry, rushed :)
scibuff just an alert. I'll use the , instead but i dont belive this will affect this issue.

Comment: Generated HTML added to main description, thanks.

Comment: Issue solved, it was because 'delete' is a reserved name for JS, thanks to @niklas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`delete()` is a reserved word in javascript, try changing the function name to `deleteIt()` or something else instead.

Comment: Thanks Niklas, it was because the function name was a reserved word! :)

i'm referencing the button as in the JS for delete i use that to ref the parent node (and it's random ID) so i can delete it from the DB and from the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `javascript:` just leave: `onclick="delete( this )"`

Comment: Is this really an answer to the question?

Comment: I had already tried that (sorry i didn't mention), no luck at all, nothing triggers, the javacript function is as follows on the page where the button is populated:

function delete(e) {
alert("TRIGGERED");
}

I do not get my alert box :(